# This is my HTTP GET request, I got connection as successfull 200.but It shows JSON response is null. How to rectify this?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsurlsession

This is my HTTP GET request, I got connection as successfull 200.but It shows JSON response is null. How to rectify this? While in POSTMAN I am getting intended response.

```
-(void) getPushNotifications :(NSString *)sandboxURL {
        NSString *url3 ;
        NSString *base_url=@"https://mag.secure.force.com/customer/services/apexrest/sandbox";
        url3=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@?sbname=%@",base_url,sandboxURL];

        NSURL *requestURL =  [NSURL URLWithString:[url3 stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:requestURL];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
        [request setValue:@"debug_logs" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cookie"];
        [request setValue:@"text/html" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
        NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                                completionHandler:
                                      ^(NSData *urlData, NSURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
                                          NSHTTPURLResponse *response = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)urlResponse;
                                          NSLog(@"Response code For delete Push History %ld", (long)[response statusCode]);
                                          if ([response statusCode])
                                          {
                                              NSDictionary *responseObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
                                              NSLog(@"Response Dict for delete Push History %@", responseObject);
                                          }else{
                                              NSLog(@"Problem in retrieving attachment");
                                          }
                                        }];
        [task resume];
}
```

Comment: You mean that `responseObject` is null? Did you tried to read use the `error` parameter of `+JSONObjectWithData:options:error:`? Is you JSON really a Dictionary at top level? Could you give us the response, with `NSString *responseStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`? Note that `if ([response statusCode])` means `if ([response statusCode] != 0)`, not if it's 200.

Comment: my response is https://demo-cs71.force.com

Comment: You mean that `responseStr` is `https://demo-cs71.force.com/`? If that's the case, your response is simply not JSON. It is the case with POSTMAN? Could it be that because your didn't sepcified in your `NS(Mutable)URLRequest` that you wanted JSON, but `text/html` it's not responding JSON?

Comment: I have tried with application/json also, bit it's also not working

Comment: Did you tried to print your `error` description with NSLog?